# Tastypie Update(PUT) username by relation cause password vanishing.

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have troubles with `excludes` property in ModelResource's Meta class.

I created ModelResource for User.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        excludes = ['password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        resource_name = 'user'
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = UserAuthorization()
```

It is pretty similar to that one from [doc.](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#limiting-data-and-access)

I send `PUT` to update `username` with:
    `{"username": "bara", "first_name": "bara", "last_name": "", "email": "bara@example.com", "last_login": "2013-10-09T15:32:55.056235","id": 7, "date_joined": "2013-10-09T15:32:55.056235"}`

Everything is perfect.

But I don't want to use this resource directly I want to use this one.

```
class ProfileResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user', full=True)

    class Meta:
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        queryset = Profile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'profile'
        excludes = ['created', 'modified']
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = ProfileAuthorization()
        ...
```

I send `PUT` to update `username` with:
    `{ "user": {"username": "barabara", "first_name": "bara", "last_name": "", "email": "bara@example.com", "last_login": "2013-10-09T15:32:55.056235", "id": 7, "date_joined": "2013-10-09T15:32:55.056235"}, "gender": 0, "birth_date": null}`

And it seems to work well but it doesn't. Password somehow has been overridden in second case.
I get `ValueError: Unknown password hashing algorithm.`
In admin panel I see:
[image]

I tried to set `excludes` in ProfileResource's Meta like `user__password` and `password` but seems to not help.

Additional information:
- User and Profile are in relation one to one.
- Python 2.7, Django 1.4.3, Tastypie 0.9.12

EDIT:
I am sorry for confusing but this happen only during `username` updating. All rest fields from User works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that the problem is that new user is created when you do the put, since it updates the user field (e.g. replace the existing one with the new one, which has no password field, it does not merge the two users).

Maybe try to use other verb?

Comment: I made mistake I updated question. This happen only when `username` field is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement dirty hack is still not tested well so please be careful:
Method of `ProfileResource`:

```
def obj_update(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        """
        Additional operations for changing username.

        Changes username in database.
        """
        bundle = super(ProfileResource, self).obj_update(bundle, **kwargs)

        username, api_key = self.get_credentials(bundle.request)
        profile = Profile.get_logged(username, api_key)
        if profile:
            try:
                if bundle.data['username'] and bundle.data['username'] != profile.user.username:
                    try:
                        User.objects.get(username=bundle.data['username'])
                        logging.warning('Username %s Already exists cannot update.' % bundle.data['username'])
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                        profile.user.username = bundle.data['username']
                        profile.user.save()

            except KeyError:
                pass

        return bundle
```

I know this is not a solution. Other option is to use directly `UserResource`.

Comment: To check if new username already exists in the system you can do this :             if Profile.objects.filter(username=username).filter(~Q(user=bundle.obj.user)):